# how to use javascript variable inside scriptlet tag

Tags: jsp, javascript, scriptlet

I want to pass a javascript variable to a scriptlet tag.
below is my code, i am using scriptlet tags inside a jsp page:

```
    <script>
    function concur(look){
    alert(look);
    <%
    String lk=request.getParameter("look");
    con.writing("HeyWow ",lk);%>        
    </script>
```

i want to pass the value of the string 'look' as an argument to the function 'writing'.

can anyone tell me how to do this ?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question and answers may help you. It was asked by me earlier today :)

[Javascript variable in asp block code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17809531/javascript-variable-in-asp-block-code)

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You have to submit your form to server as a normal submit process or via ajax call and only after that to have access to variables in the request.